# Can PDFs run HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a dumb idea to try to make a program that isn't blocked on any computer, as it would be embedded in a PDF (I heard that Javascript can be run in a PDF). It would run HTML5 and Javascript(along with a little bit of CSS) inside the PDF file and would mostly use the `canvas` element in HTML5 and WebGL in Javascript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No.

PDFs can embed JS in the same way that HTML can embed JS.

PDFs can’t embed HTML. They do not have anything equivalent to a canvas element.

Comment: Can the JS in a PDF use objects such as window and document?

Comment: See the API documentation: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/jsapiref/

Answer (score 0):

Embedding HTML5, JavaScript, and WebGL in a PDF is possible but comes with limitations, security risks, and potential compatibility issues with different viewers. For interactive content, using web browsers is a more practical and reliable approach.